# In beagleboard xm hog descriptor algorithm takes huge time for object detection

Tags: beagleboard

I am trying to perform object detection with hog descriptor algorithm. I done it in my Ubuntu 12.04 system with processing time of 300ms. Then I tried to perform the same using beagle board xm rev c3 and then I got some problems. The major issue is the processing time it takes is too high, almost 45 seconds for grabbing an image and detecting an object.  I could reduced the processing time to 8.5 seconds by changing double precision to single precision.

```
But still it takes more than 8 seconds.As in my knowledge it is due to one single function 
  hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, THRESHOLD, cv::Size(2,2), cv::Size(0,0), 1.05, 2);

which takes 8 seconds to process.

I saw in some sites that this function require huge processing power to process so we need some better GPU.

But in our case beagle-board xm has 1GHz processor and 512 MB Ram.

(My Ubuntu system has 2 GHz processor and 1 GB Ram)
```

I am processing image with 320x240 pixels. But I am taking a small portion of the whole image by cropping. Then it executed in 300ms in the system but taking 8.5 seconds in beagle board.

I am using opencv 2.4.2.

I need to reduce the processing time from 8 seconds to at least below 2 seconds.

```
Is any other solution?

Could anyone help me?
```